# Magento 2 admin message notifications are not display on redirect to same page

Tags: magento2, admin, messages, adminnotification

On select an option from dropdown, I am getting value in `phtml` file and from there in `js function` , i am redirecting to my controllers.

Everything works fine but only `admin message notifications` are not displaying while i used `return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();`

It is redirecting to same page but messages are not displaying.
But when i gave `$resultRedirect->setPath('/');`

It is redirect to dashboard and displaying message at dashboard. but its not working for same page redirect.

Can anyone help me where is the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting Admin notification, Don't call the block from controller. Always call the block from the layout file only. Otherwise Magento 2 default admin notification like succes , error will not display.

Comment: Please, elaborate the processes and how to call the block from layout file